# Xcode keeps building on Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I've converted my Swift 2.3 project to swift 3. Now the compiler doesn't throw any errors anymore but it keeps compiling. CPU is like 100% and it keeps compiling for like 50 minutes or more if you don't stop it.

Xcode keeps saying Building .. | Compiling Swift source files

In the build log it stops always on the same swift files. The swift files are just simple model classes so I don't know what the problem could be.

I had the same problem in swift 2 but that was caused by the `??` operator. I refactored the code to remove the `??` operator so it can't be this anymore.

How can I find out what slows down the compile time to endless?

My models all look the same:

```
class Test: InputContract {
    var appointmentDate: Date!
    var startTime: String!
    var endTime: String!
    var registerDescription: String!
    var subjectKey: String!
    var channelCode: String!
    var relationManagerHrId: String = ""
    var employeeUserCode: String = ""
    var smsReminderMobileNumber: String = ""
    var smsReminderMobileNumberSequence: String!
    var contactPhoneNumber: String = ""
    var contactPhoneNumberSequence: String!
    var smsReminder: Bool = false

 override func retrieveInputDictionary() -> NSDictionary {
        return ["description" : self.registerDescription, "appointmentDate" : Utils.formattedDate(self.appointmentDate),
                "startTime" : self.startTime, "endTime" : self.endTime, "subjectKey" : self.subjectKey, "channelCode" : self.channelCode, "smsReminder" : self.smsReminder ? "true" : "false", "relationManagerHrId" : self.relationManagerHrId, "employeeUserCode" : self.employeeUserCode,
                "smsReminderMobileNumber" : self.smsReminderMobileNumber, "contactPhoneNumber" : self.contactPhoneNumber, "smsReminderMobileNumberSequence" : self.smsReminderMobileNumberSequence, "contactPhoneNumberSequence" : self.contactPhoneNumberSequence
        ]
    }
}
```

InputContract is:

```
protocol InputDictionaryMapper {
    func retrieveInputDictionary() -> NSDictionary
    func retrievePublicInputDictionary() -> NSDictionary
}

class InputContract: Model, InputDictionaryMapper {

    func retrieveInputDictionary() -> NSDictionary {
        fatalError("Each inputContract implementation must implement it's own method: \(NSStringFromClass(type(of: self)))")
    }

    func retrievePublicInputDictionary() -> NSDictionary {
        fatalError("Each inputContract implementation must implement it's own method: \(NSStringFromClass(type(of: self)))")
    }

    required init(json: JSON) {
        fatalError("init(json:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

And model is just a base class that has another init for json too.

When I run the analyser on the build log then all my models are taking soo long to create the NSDictionary. But Why?

Comment: 1. Have you tried to clean project/restarting Xcode/etc.?
2. Have you tried to compile this Swift file in a separate project?

If not, please post the contents of the Swift file on which it hangs.

Comment: hello, i have same problem, you got any solution?

Comment: @fiks I edited my question with the class.

Comment: It might be a problem with type inference. Could you please try storing your dictionary in a variable, e.g. `let dict: [String: Any]  = //...initialisation`. And then return `dict as NSDictionary`. Also, do you really need NSDictionary? Why don't you use normal Swift Dictionary?

Comment: The first on I already tried the variable is not the solution. I also think there is a problem. But I thought NSDictionary is interchangeable with Dictionary? So you suggest I remove NSDictionary and return Dictionary<String, Any> like this?

Comment: Yes, you could try that. 
P.S. I have compiled it in a sample project. The compilation time was pretty fast. But I had to remove a call to ` Utils.formattedDate(self.appointmentDate)`, because I don't have access to this class. This might be a problem too.

Comment: That is just a objective c category on NSDate. I'm going to try this return Dictionary<String: Any> because I have a lot of models.

Comment: I refactored everything to use dictionary instead of NSDictionary. Still it hangs on files. It can't compile the whole project.

Comment: Did you try to remove the part with `Utils.formattedDate(self.appointmentDate)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the problem was that we had a lot of dictionaries created like this:

```
let dict = ["key": value, "key2": value2]
```

If you rewrite this as

```
var dict: [String: Any] = [String: Any]()
dict["key"] = value
dict["key2"] = value2
```

then the compiler magically only takes 15 to 20 ms per model instead of 2000 ms per model.

You can try it yourself with the buildtime analyser app :-)

Comment: actually, the first dictionary is actually an array :) Wouldn't it be enough to define `let dict: [String: Any] = ...`. Type inference can be slow and declaring the type should be enough.

Comment: Sorry you are right the first one was an array. I edited the code. Yes ofcourse you can drop off the [String: Any]() part. It was just to make it clear.

Comment: What happens if you try `let dict: [String: Any] = ["key": value, "key2": value2]`, ie the same thing but with a type defined?

Comment: The same happens. You really need to rewrite it the other way. That solved my endless compile but the project has almost 400 models...

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem after migrating the project to swift 3, but after lots of R&D I found a solution. It was taking time because of dictionaries and array created without data type.